# Revolution Slider (Wordpress) Hiding Dropdown Menu (Superfish)

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position, z-index, superfish

I'm currently coding a theme that calls for a revolution slider at the top of the page and I also need a dropdown menu system.

I'm trying to use Superfish and that works fine but when you hover to see the dropdown menu items, they show up underneath my slider.

I've tried playing around with z-index (including adding position: relative) but I just cannot get this to work. I've tried adding z-index of a ridiculous amount to the header, the menu, the list items basically everything I could but there must be something I'm missing.

I've found a few answers by Googling but it always suggests z-index.

The site can be found at:

http://clients.benpalmer.me/medina/introduction-to-south-arabian-civilization/#sidr-main

The dropdown menu should show up over the slider and is under the 'Inscriptions' menu item.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: your `header.main` css style has `overflow:hidden;` this has nothing to do with the slider

Comment: That's done it! A little ashamed of such a rookie mistake actually!

Comment: glad i could help, happens to the best of us